# Cambiar attributos de una table

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo y lo que deseo que haga es que al darle a la imagen coja el `id` de ese `tr` en concreto y todos los textBox se vuelvan `enable`...

Yo lo he intentado con `document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;` ... pero solo me hace la primera fila y al recoger la `id` de la fila no se como escribirlo.

```js
function modify(id){
    
       var cell = id.parentNode;
       var row = cell.parentNode;
        row=row.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
       document.getElementById("apellidos").disabled = false;
       document.getElementById("telef").disabled = false;
       document.getElementById("email").disabled = false;
       document.getElementById("cargo").disabled = false;
     
    }
```

```html
<table name="table1" id="table1">
              <tr>
                 <th>1</th>
                 <th>2</th>
                 <th>3</th>
                 <th>4</th>
                 <th>5</th>
                 <th>6</th>
                 <th>7</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  
                  <th><input id='name' name='name' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='apellidos' name='apellidos' size='10' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='telef' name='telef' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='email' name='email' size='12' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='cargo' name='cargo' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"></th>
                 <th >
                    <img onclick=modify(this); src="--.jpg">
                    <img onclick=opc(this); src="--.jpg">
                    <img onclick=delete(this); src="--.jpg">

                 </th>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                  
                  <th><input id='name' name='name' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='apellidos' name='apellidos' size='10' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='telef' name='telef' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='email' name='email' size='12' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='cargo' name='cargo' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"></th>
                 <th >
                    <img onclick=modify(this); src="--.jpg">
                    <img onclick=opc(this); src="--.jpg">
                    <img onclick=delete(this); src="--.jpg">

                 </th>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                  
                  <th><input id='name' name='name' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='apellidos' name='apellidos' size='10' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='telef' name='telef' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='email' name='email' size='12' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input id='cargo' name='cargo' size='8' value='1' disabled></input></th>
                 <th><input type="checkbox" name="email" value="1"></th>
                 <th >
                    <img onclick=modify(this); src="--.jpg">
                    <img onclick=opc(this); src="--.jpg">
                    <img onclick=delete(this); src="--.jpg">

                 </th>
              </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: Solo tienes una fila con `id='name'` por eso solo te coge esa fila. Tus tr no tienen id, no puedes cogerlo así... También te recomiendo no usar el mismo id más de una vez en el mismo documento, si vas a repetir utiliza `class`. Al hacer el `onclick` en línea es recomendable que pongas la función entre comillas `onclick="modify(this)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `id` es algo único.

Ergo siempre devolverá la primera ocurrencia. No lo uses más de una vez.

Para tu problema yo pondría un id al `tr` y luego al `id` de los inputs de dentro una combinación del estilo `name + idDelTR` -> `name1`, `email1`...

En la función `modify` añadiria la variable `trID` para concatenarlo al buscar por id como en:

```
var trID = row.id;
document.getElementById("email" + trID).disabled = false;
```

```js
function modify(elem) {

  var cell = elem.parentNode;
  var row = cell.parentNode;
  var trID = row.id;


  document.getElementById("name" + trID).disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("apellidos" + trID).disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("telef" + trID).disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("email" + trID).disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("cargo" + trID).disabled = false;

}
```

```html
<table name="table1" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='1'>

    <th><input id='name1' name='name1' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='apellidos1' name='apellidos1' size='10' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='telef1' name='telef1' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='email1' name='email1' size='12' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='cargo1' name='cargo1' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="emailC1" value="1"></th>
    <th>
      <img onclick="modify(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="opc(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="delete(this);" src="--.jpg">

    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='2'>

    <th><input id='name2' name='name2' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='apellidos2' name='apellidos2' size='10' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='telef2' name='telef2' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='email2' name='email2' size='12' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='cargo2' name='cargo2' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="emailC2" value="1"></th>
    <th>
      <img onclick="modify(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="opc(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="delete(this);" src="--.jpg">

    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='3'>

    <th><input id='name3' name='name3' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='apellidos3' name='apellidos3' size='10' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='telef3' name='telef3' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='email3' name='email3' size='12' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='cargo3' name='cargo3' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="emailC3" value="1"></th>
    <th>
      <img onclick="modify(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="opc(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="delete(this);" src="--.jpg">

    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

También puedes hacer una `query` para evitar líneas "repetitivas".

Con

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[id*='"+trID+"']").forEach(elem => elem.disabled = false);
```

estás recogiendo todos los `input`'s que tengan un `id` que termine (con el operador `*=` ) en el número del `id` del `tr`.

Después haces un `forEach` para que cada uno se quite el `disabled`

```js
function modify(elem) {

  var cell = elem.parentNode;
  var row = cell.parentNode;
  var trID = row.id;


    document.querySelectorAll("input[id*='" + trID + "']").forEach(elem => elem.disabled = false);

}
```

```html
<table name="table1" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='1'>

    <th><input id='name1' name='name1' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='apellidos1' name='apellidos1' size='10' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='telef1' name='telef1' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='email1' name='email1' size='12' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='cargo1' name='cargo1' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="emailC1" value="1"></th>
    <th>
      <img onclick="modify(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="opc(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="delete(this);" src="--.jpg">

    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='2'>

    <th><input id='name2' name='name2' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='apellidos2' name='apellidos2' size='10' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='telef2' name='telef2' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='email2' name='email2' size='12' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='cargo2' name='cargo2' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="emailC2" value="1"></th>
    <th>
      <img onclick="modify(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="opc(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="delete(this);" src="--.jpg">

    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='3'>

    <th><input id='name3' name='name3' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='apellidos3' name='apellidos3' size='10' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='telef3' name='telef3' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='email3' name='email3' size='12' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input id='cargo3' name='cargo3' size='8' value='1' disabled>
    </th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" name="emailC3" value="1"></th>
    <th>
      <img onclick="modify(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="opc(this);" src="--.jpg">
      <img onclick="delete(this);" src="--.jpg">

    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al usar `document.getElementById("name")`obtienes sólo el primer elemento con el id que buscas, para obtener todos, debes usar `document.getElementsByName("name")`